# Show that there exists a sequence of continuous functions $\{g_n\}$ so that $g_n\to f$ as $n\to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Following this question:[Show that every Lebesgue integrable function can be approximated in norm and almost everywhere by a sequence of continuous functions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1563669/show-that-every-lebesgue-integrable-function-can-be-approximated-in-norm-and-alm)

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Show that there exists a sequence of continuous functions $\{g_n\}$ so that $g_n\to f$ a.e. as $n\to \infty$.

In that answer, we find a continuous function $F$ such that $\|F-\chi_{E}\|< \epsilon$ if $E$ is a set of finite measure. But it seems that we did not get a sequence of continuous functions $\{g_n\}$?

---

My proof:

Suppose $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a step function $h=\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n\chi_{E_n}$ such that $\|f-h\|_{L^1} < \epsilon$, where $E_i$ is bounded intervals.

In that answer, for each $\chi_{E_i}$ we find a continuous function $F_i$ such that $\|F_i-\chi_{E_i}\|< \epsilon$.

But how to show that $g_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n a_iF_i$ satisfy
$$
\|f-g_n\|_1\to 0?
$$

---

I try to write
$$
\|f-g_N\|_1=\|f-h+h-g_N\|_1\le \|f-h\|_1+\|h-g_N\|_1=?
$$
where we know that the first term less than $\epsilon$.

But the second term
$$
\|h-g_N\|_1=\int |\sum_{i=1}^Na_i(\chi_{E_i}-F_i)|
$$

Comment: Better call it $g_\epsilon$, not $g_N$. Then, things should be clear.

Comment: @AnneBauval What do you mean? But how to get $\|f-h_n\|\to 0$ for a sequence of continuous functions $\{h_n\}$?

Comment: I meant that your $h$, hence $N$, hence (badly named) $g_N$ all depend on $\epsilon$, and that the answer to your "But can we say that as $N→0$
, $∥f−g_N∥→0$
?" (which you removed some minutes ago) was: no, what we can say is that as $\epsilon\to0$, $∥f−g_\epsilon∥→0$.

Comment: To make sure that your second term is also $<\epsilon$,  simply choose your $F_n$s such that $\|F_n-\chi_{E_n}\|< \frac{\epsilon}{N|a_n|}$. And again: your $g_N$ or $g_n$ should be named $g_\epsilon$.

Comment: I don't think a bounty is worth: the linked post already does the job.

Comment: @AnneBauval Ok, I see. So here we choose $\epsilon=1/n$? Then as $n\to\infty$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f-g_n\|\le \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}=0$?

Comment: No. For each (real) $\epsilon>0$, after $\epsilon$-approximating $f$ by some step function $$h_\epsilon=\sum_{n=1}^{N_\epsilon}a_{\epsilon,n}\chi_{E_{\epsilon,n}},$$ you construct (as hinted above) a continuous function $g_\epsilon$ which $\epsilon$-approximates $h_\epsilon$, so that $$\|f-g_\epsilon\|\le2\epsilon.$$ Only after that, if you really insist on having a sequence, you may notice for instance that $$\|f-g_{1/n}\|\le2/n.$$

Comment: @AnneBauval I think that is same think? Here our sequence is $\{g_k\}_{k\ge 1}$, for $k=1/n$? But why write $g_{1/n}$?

Comment: To prevent you from confusing integer indices like the $N$s and $n$s appearing in the construction of $h$ and $g$ with the final indices of the sequence of functions, like you are still doing in your post, I insist on my advice to first define $g_\epsilon$ for any positive real number $\epsilon$. Then, if you want a sequence, take any sequence of positive real numbers $\epsilon_k$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\epsilon_k=0$. To keep the notations consistent, your sequence of functions will then not be "$g_k$" but $g_{\epsilon_k}$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you. So if I try to prove the stronger statement that find a continuous sequence $g_n$ so that $g_n\to f$ a.e. How to prove that based on our $L^1$ convergence result?

Comment: It is not a stronger statement but a corollary. Use that every sequence which converges in $L^p$ (for some $p\ge1$) has a subsequence which converges a.e. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2486114